# How to validate a composed_of ActiveRecord class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I like to use composed_of in my Rails apps, it helps me craft nice problem-space objects from the raw database data.

I have a problem though, what is the best way to validate them, ideally using the automagic ActiveRecord way?

Sometimes validating the raw data is enough, but often the object is too complex for that, and you want to report meaningful information (close to the composing object) to the user.

I found this: http://www.stephenchu.com/2008/05/rails-composedof-validation.html but it doesn't seem very elegant or Rails-like.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do this (an example from one of my apps):

```
composed_of :cents_cost_amount,
            :class_name => "Money",
            :mapping => [%w(cents_cost_amount cents), %w(currency currency_as_string)],
            :constructor => Proc.new { |cents, currency| Money.new(cents || 0, currency || Money.default_currency) },
            :converter => Proc.new { |value| value.respond_to?(:to_money) ? value.to_money : raise(ArgumentError, "Can't convert #{value.class} to Money") }   

validates :cents_cost_amount,             
          :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0, 
                            :less_than_or_equal_to => 1000000, 
                            :message => "Only amounts in the range 0 to 10000.00 are allowed."  }
```

It's hard to give you more insight into your problem without specific example.